# Apache URL Rewriting little bit complex

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I would like to rewrite an url according to a specific model.
From:

```
http://myhost/aa/bb/value1?var2=value2&var3=value3
```

To:

```
http://myhost/aa/bb/index/index?var1=value1&var2=value2&var3=value3
```

- value1: [:0-9TZ-]
- value2: [0-9]
- value3: [0-9]

Here is the solution I thought was good :

```
RewriteRule ^/?([\:0-9TZ-]*)\?(.*)$ /aa/bb/index/index?var1=$1&$2 [R,L]
```

But, here are the errors I get (I tried each one alone) :

- **:** : give me an 404 error (aa/bb/2015-09-15T10:00Z not found)
- **\?(.*)$** and **&$2**: gives me an 404 error (aa/bb/2015-09-15T1000Z not found, whereas I was looking for http://myhost/aa/bb/2015-09-15T1000Z?count=2)

But it works if I try with:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9TZ-]*) /aa/bb/index/index?var1=$1 [R,L]
```

and

```
http://myhost/aa/bb/2015-09-15T1000Z
```

Any help would by really appreciated.

Quentin

Comment: isn't `:` escaped as `%3A`?

Comment: I got the same problem if I replace my ":" with "%3A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't match against the query string in a rewrite rule, but since you aren't changing the query string at all, you can simply use your second attempt and include a `QSA` flag so that the existing query string gets appended:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9TZ:-]*) /aa/bb/index/index?var1=$1 [R,L,QSA]
```

You can also include a `:` in the square brackets to trap the colon. Any URL encoding gets decoded before the URI is sent through rewrite rules.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for the others parameters (var2 and var3), but I still got an 404 error with this URL : **http://myhost/aa/bb/2015-09-15T10:00Z**